# Implicitly typed arrays: why we can't set array size explicitly?

Tags: c#

The C# language specification (7.6.10.4) says, that there are tree kinds of array creation expressions:

> new non-array-type [ expression-list ] rank-specifiersopt array-initializeropt
>   new array-type array-initializer
>   new rank-specifier array-initializer

The third one is intended for implicitly typed arrays:

```
var foo = new[] { 1, 2, 3 };
```

The question: is there any weighty reason to forbid to set array size explicitly in case of implicitly typed array?

It looks like asymmetric behavior, comparing with this syntax:

```
var foo = new int[3] { 1, 2, 3 };
```

**Update**.

A little clarification. The only advantage for combination of explicitly set array size and array initializer I can see, is the compile-time check for initializer length. If I've declared the array of three `int`s, the initializer must contain three `int`s.

I think, the same advantage is true for the implicitly typed arrays. Of course, to use this advantage or not to use is the personal preference.

Comment: +1. I must admit.. I've never even noticed this (I just do it the first way every time..).

Comment: You're discussing anonymous array initialization. If I understand you, you are asking if anonymous arrays could be defined a little 'tighter'. My suspicion is they could have been designed this way, but I don't see any clear advantage. It's like drawing a line in the sand. Microsoft developers have to draw it somewhere. Why not there?

Comment: What would be the point of allowing this?

Comment: @BrianRasmussen: and what is the point of allowing this for explicitly typed arrays? I think, the point is the same - if I've declared, that there must be 3 elements, the initializer *must* contain 3 elements.

Comment: @Dennis, while I think it's more of a philosophy point than anything else, its a good one +1

Comment: For an explicitly-typed array you *need* a syntax for specifying the size so you can write `var foo = new int[3];` without an initializer.  You don't need that syntax for an implicitly-typed array.  That might explain some of the asymmetry, but, it doesn't explain the omission and, yes, it would be nice to have.

Answer (score 2):

[The rank specifier is not needed because it is already supplied by the number of elements in the initialization list.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0a7fscd0%28VS.80%29.aspx)

Comment: I think he realizes this. the question seems to be, why this way instead of that? the OP could arguably define the anonymous array of fixed size. To which I say, all approaches are equally reasonable as long their implications and forms are consitant.

Comment: @DaveA: exactly. Personally, I never set array length, if there is an initializer. But, if it is allowed for explicitly typed arrays, I can't see any reason to forbid it for implicitly typed.

Comment: @Dennis, Microsoft has designed like that only, if you mention the RANK and items together how compiler will check at the time of compilation?

Comment: @Anandkumar: the same way it checks for the explicitly typed arrays. I can't see any contradictions. :)

Comment: The link has expired. Can we bring it back?

Answer (score 0):

I think one difference here is that this syntax can be seen as first creating a typed array, and then populating it:

```
var foo = new int[3] { 1, 2, 3 };
```

This is similar to the way we can declare and initialize other datatypes in a single statement:

```
var list = new List<string>{ "a", "b", "c" };
var dict = new Dictionary<string, string>{ {"a", "b"}, {"c", "d"} };
```

The first statement creates and `int[3]` and populates it.  The second and third statements create a `List<string>` or `Dictionary<string, string>` and populate them.

But if you do this:

```
var foo = new[3] { 1, 2, 3 };
```

this is not the same thing.  There is no such datatype as a `[3]`, so unlike the other 2 examples, this isn't a case of first creating a specific object and populating it. This is a special syntax for creating implicitly-typed arrays, where the array and its contents are inferred from the contents of the braces, and then created.

I don't know enough to say why that kind of syntax *shouldn't* exist, but I think this is a plausible explanation for what you see as an asymmetry.

Comment: > this isn't a case of first creating an object and populating it - I see your point, but I can't agree with it. The type inference means only that type is inferred by the compiler, instead of to be explicitly set by the programmer. This doesn't mean, that compiler emits an IL, which creates an object of unknown type. If you'll look into emitted IL, you'll see concrete type.

Comment: Yes, that's all true, but my point is that they are two different types of syntax. It's often the case that syntax patterns that involve inference don't allow you to insert constraints wherever you choose to.  For example, you can define a concrete method `string F(string a){ return a; }` and pass `F` to a method G that takes a `Func<string, string>` using `G(F)`, but you can't do this: `G(string (string st) => return st;)` if you want to make absolutely sure that the `st` in your anonymous function body and the returned values are strings. I think this is a similar idea.